# downgrade drupal 7 to drupal 6

Tags: 7

I need to downgrade Drupal 7 installation to Drupal 6, how should I handle it? I have pretty much blank Drupal 7 install (w/ bunch of users, which I really don't want to loose), but the module that I need only works on Drupal 6.

*** UPDATE ***

following is a module that I'd like to use w/ Drupal: [Clickbank IPN | drupal.org](http://drupal.org/project/clickbank_ipn) and as you see developer(s) don't have anything other then d6 release.

Is there a way to export users from D7 and import then to D6?

Comment: More info would help. Did you make backups of your databases before upgrading? If so, it's a bit easier. Otherwise, your best bet might be to hire somebody to port that module to D7 -- *never* migrate a live site between major iterations (I.e., D6 -> D7) without setting up a duplicate testing site beforehand and making backups.

Answer (score 2):

You wont be able to find any easy solution to downgrade from 7 to 6. The best option is to either find an alternative to the module that is not available for D7 or check the issue queue of that module you might find the dev release of the module. OR If only users are important to you then just export the users from D7 and import them on D6.

Comment: unfortunately module doesn't support d7 nor there is a -dev version is available, my only choice is d6. how/where do I export users from/to Drupal?

Comment: What is the module name that is not available for D7 ?

Comment: I updated my main question with that module ( module's name is: clickbank_ipn)

Comment: Checked the module, unfortunately D7 version is not available. Better option is try to upgrade the module to D7 by your self and contribute to community. :)

Comment: I'm not a coder( but if I were, I'd definitely would do  that), so how would I go by export/import users?

Comment: I am not 100% sure about the workflow but try to export users from D7 with any modules like : "views data export". Then import the users in D6 using : "feeds". I

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading from Drupal 7 to Drupal 6 involves a lot of manual work. For example, the password hashing algorithm in Drupal 7 is not compatible with the one in Drupal 6.

I strongly advice against it and instead look for some other way to implement the functionality you are missing.

Comment: as i just mentioned unfortunately module doesn't support d7, so as much as I'd like to stay w/ D7 instead of D6, I have no choice...

Comment: There's always a choice. Implement a module of your own, look for a similar module for D7.

Comment: if this would be some popular module then yes, I'd consider that instead of moving to D6 but this isn't and there are no similar modules, and development cycle it'd take to implement this module on my own is too great